# Using xargs to assign stdin to a variable

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

All that I really want to do is make sure everything in a pipeline succeeded and assign the last stdin to a variable.  Consider the following dumbed down scenario:

`` x=`exit 1|cat` ``

When I run `declare -a`, I see this:

`declare -a PIPESTATUS='([0]="0")'`

I need some way to notice the `exit 1`, so I converted it to this:

`exit 1|cat|xargs -I {} x={}`

And `declare -a` gave me:

`declare -a PIPESTATUS='([0]="1" [1]="0" [2]="0")'`

That is what I wanted, so I tried to see what would happen if the `exit 1` didn't happen:

`echo 1|cat|xargs -I {} x={}`

But it fails with:

`xargs: x={}: No such file or directory`

Is there any way to have xargs assign `{}` to `x`?  What about other methods of having `PIPESTATUS` work and assigning the stdin to a variable?

Note:  these examples are dumbed down.  I'm not really doing an `exit 1`, `echo 1` or a `cat`, but used these commands to simplify so we can focus on my particular issue.

Answer (score 3):

`xargs` is run in a child process, as are all the commands you call. So they can't effect the environment of your shell.

You might be able to do something with named pipes (`mkfifo`), or possible bash's `read` function?

EDIT:

Maybe just redirect the output to a file, then you can use PIPESTATUS:

```
command1 | command2 | command3 >/tmp/tmpfile
## Examine PIPESTATUS
X=$(cat /tmp/tmpfile)
```

Comment: I was thinking read could do something like that.  echo 1|read x didn't work.  Do you have an example?

Answer (score 3):

When you use backticks (or the preferred `$()`) you're running those commands in a subshell. The `PIPESTATUS` you're getting is for the assignment rather than the piped commands in the subshell.

When you use `xargs`, it knows nothing about the shell so it can't make variable assignments.

Try `set -o pipefail` then you can get the status from `$?`.

Comment: pipefail is a good option to consider.  However, I wish I could get teh PIPESTATUS for everything in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

How about ...

```
read x <<<"$(echo 1)"
read x < <(echo 1)

echo "$x"
```

Comment: Interesting thought.  Using (exit 1|cat) still doesn't properly populate PIPESTATUS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just populate a new array?

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a result < <(echo a | cat | cat; echo "PIPESTATUS='${PIPESTATUS[*]}'" )
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a result < <(echo a | exit 1 | cat; echo "PIPESTATUS='${PIPESTATUS[*]}'" )

echo "${#result[@]}"
echo "${result[@]}"
echo "${result[0]}"
echo "${result[1]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already a few helpful solutions.  It turns out that I actually had an example that matches the question as framed above; close-enough *anyway*.

Consider this:

```
 XX=$(ls -l *.cpp | wc -l  | xargs -I{} echo {})
 echo $XX
 3
```

Meaning that I had 3 x `.cpp` files to in my working directory.  Now `$XX` is 3 and I can make use of that result in my script.  It is contrived, because I don't actually need the `xargs` in this example.  It works though.

In the example from the question ...

```
x=`exit 1|cat`
```

I don't think that will give you what was specified.  `exit` will quit the sub-shell before the `cat` gets a mention.  Also on that note,

I might start with something like

```
declare -a PIPESTATUS='([0]="0")'
x=$?
```

`x` now has the status from the last command.

Answer (score 0):

Assign each line of input to an array, e.g. all python files in a directory

```
declare -a pyFiles=($(ls -l *.py | awk '{print $9}'))
```

where $9 is the nineth field in ls -l corresponding to the filename