# Pipe status after command substitution

Tags: bash, pipe

I'd like to send the result of a series of commands to a variable:

```
variable=$(a | few | commands)
```

However, the command substitution resets `PIPESTATUS`, so I can't inspect where it went wrong after the fact. One solution would be to use `mktemp` and put the result there temporarily:

```
variable_file=$(mktemp) || exit 1
a | few | commands > $variable_file
exit_codes="${PIPESTATUS[*]}"
variable=$(<$variable_file)
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: This is a good question indeed. I think there is no better solution than yours, I hope someone proves me wrong ;-) You probably know about "set -o pipefail", but anyway this is (more or less) orthogonal to your question.

Comment: Ok now I am intrigued because I do this same way you do... and it works... but if there is something more elegant... let me have it...

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450960/using-xargs-to-assign-stdin-to-a-variable) for more ideas. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413166/bash-redirect-and-append-stdout-and-stderr-to-file-and-terminal).

Comment: Regardless of the approach I'd suggest `exit_codes=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")` instead of `exit_codes="${PIPESTATUS[*]}"`, so that you keep the codes as an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kinda hacky but I think you could fudge it like this.

```
variable=$(a | few | commands; echo ": ${PIPESTATUS[*]}")
PIPESTATUS=(${variable##*: })
variable=${variable%:*}
variable=${variable%$'\n'}
```

Comment: +1, neat as long as you know what to expect from the commands.

Comment: if the output from `a | few | commands` is needed, could the status be sent through file descriptor 3?

Comment: @jozxyqk The output is captured into `$variable` (after being mixed in and split out).

Answer (score 1):

Building on [ephemient's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410201/pipe-status-after-command-substitution/4411699#4411699) answer, if we need the output of the piped commands stored without them being mixed in with the pipestatus codes, but we don't really care what the exit codes themselves are (just that they all succeeded), we can do:

`variable=$(a | few | commands; [[ ${PIPESTATUS[*]} == "0 0 0" ]])`

This will check on the status of all the piped command status in the above example and if its exit code is not 0, will set `$?` to 1 (`false`)

If you want to exit with a different code instead of 1, you could capture the contents of `PIPESTATUS[#]`, e.g. `r_code=${PIPESTATUS[2]}`, and then use `(exit ${r_code[2]})` instead of `false`.

Below captures all the codes of PIPESTATUS, ensures they're all 0, and if not, sets the exit code to be the `$?` value of `commands`:

```
declare -a r_code 
variable=$(a | few | commands
           r_code=(${PIPESTATUS[@]})
           [[ ${r_code[*]} == "0 0 0" ]] || (exit ${r_code[2]})
)

echo ${?}         # echoes the exit code of `commands`
echo ${variable}  # echoes only the output of a | few | commands
```

Comment: Good ideas for some more flexible options. You could also use `set -o pipefail` before running the commands to avoid having to check the whole `PIPESTATUS` contents for non-zeros.