# Mysql error handling in queries bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I need to catch any invalid credentials while connecting to `MariaDB`, and overwrite the `stderr` stream explaining the error.

I have tried to use the following since it seemed to be the easiest and shortest code, but the database throws it's own error instead of displaying mine so I do not think the condition is even working.

right after the `mysql` command

```
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "There is something wrong with the arguments provided">&2
    exit 2
else
    : #some code
fi

TABLES=$(mysql --skip-column-name -u $USER -pPASSWORD $DB -e "SHOW TABLES;" | grep -v '+' | cut -d' ' -f2)

if [ "$?" -eq- 0 ]; then
    echo "There is something wrong with the arguments provided">&2
    exit 2
else
    : #some code
fi
```

I was expecting to see my `stderr` message appearing instead it is showing the `mariadb` error message on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit status of a pipeline is the status of the last command in the pipeline. So in your case, it's the status of `cut`, not `mysql`.

You can use the `PIPESTATUS` array to get the exit status of other commands in the pipeline. However, this is tricky when the pipeline is in a command substitution, because you need `PIPESTATUS` from the subshell. See [Pipe status after command substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410201/pipe-status-after-command-substitution)

If you don't want to see the database error message, you need to redirect stderr.

You need to check if the status is *not* `0`. In the shell, `0` means success.

```
TABLES=$(mysql --skip-column-name -u $USER -pPASSWORD $DB -e "SHOW TABLES;" 2>/dev/null | grep -v '+' | cut -d' ' -f2; echo ": ${PIPESTATUS[0]}")
status=${TABLES##*: }
if [ $status -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "There is something wrong with the arguments provided">&2
    exit 2
else
    # Remove the appended status
    TABLES=${TABLES%:*}
    TABLES=${TABLES%$'\n'}
fi
```

Comment: thanks, it is now working. However what about a mysql command which has a > $TABLE.desc near the end, can i just check the $? or will it also report the > $TABLE.desc operation ?

Comment: That should work as desired. `$?` will be `0` if the command is successful AND it was able to write to the file. If either fails you'll get a non-zero, status.